# Matrix of polynomial elements

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sympy

I am using NumPy for operations on matrices, to calculate matrixA * matrixB, the trace of the matrix, etc... And elements of my matrices are integers. But what I want to know is if there is possibility to work with matrices of polynomials. So for instance I can work with matrices such as `[x,y;a,b]`, not `[1,1;1,1]`, and when I calculate the trace it provides me with the polynomial x + b, and not 2. Is there some polynomial class in NumPy which matrices can work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the [SymPy Matrices module](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/matrices/matrices.html). SymPy is a symbolic mathematics library for Python which is quite interoperable with NumPy, especially for simple matrix manipulation tasks such as this.

```
>>> from sympy import symbols, Matrix
>>> from numpy import trace
>>> x, y, a, b = symbols('x y a b')
>>> M = Matrix(([x, y], [a, b]))
>>> M
Matrix([
[x, y],
[a, b]])
>>> trace(M)
b + x
>>> M.dot(M)
[a*y + x**2, a*b + a*x, b*y + x*y, a*y + b**2]
```